# Why does this example of global residue theorem not work?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

This question was previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396551/why-does-this-example-of-global-residue-theorem-not-work). I am posting it here also to increase the potential number of people who will see it. I realize that this question might not be entirely in the spirit of mathoverflow. Please bear with me if you could. I am really eager to learn the resolution of the below problem.

Consider the following two form in two complex variables $z_1$ and $z_2$ on $\mathbb{C}\otimes\mathbb{C}$ (where each $\mathbb{C}$ is mapped to a punctured sphere):

$$F(z_1,z_2)=\frac{1}{z_1 z_2}\frac{1}{ f_1(z_1,z_2)}\frac{1}{ f_2(z_1,z_2)}dz_1\wedge dz_2$$

where functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are defined as:

$$f_1(z_1,z_2)=a+z_1+\frac{z_1}{z_1+z_2}~~~~~,~~~~~f_2(z_1,z_2)=b+z_2+\frac{z_2}{z_1+z_2}$$

and $a,b$ are complex parameters. The global residue theorem states that the sum of all residues  gives zero for any function that is holomorphic everywhere up to a finite amount of points (since, by contour deformation on the direct disc product under the generalized Cauchy measure, this corresponds to an integral over a closed contour with no poles enclosed). Let us denote by $R_F([z_1],[z_2])$ the residue obtained from $F(z_1,z_2)$ while localizing to zero the poles $[z_1]$ and $[z_2]$ from the denominator, which are associated with varying $z_1$ and $z_2$ respectively. With this, the global residue theorem yields for $F(z_1,z_2)$:

$$R_F(f_1,f_2)+R_F(z_1,f_2)+R_F(f_1,z_2)+R_F(z_1,z_2)=0$$

In this case there are no poles at infinity. Now it is relatively easy to check that we get:

$$z_1=\frac{-a(1+a+b)}{a+b}~~~,~~~z_2=\frac{-b(1+a+b)}{a+b}~~~\Rightarrow ~~~R_F(f_1,f_2)=\frac{a+b}{ab(1+a+b)}$$
$$z_1=0~~~,~~~z_2=-1-b~~~\Rightarrow ~~~R_F(z_1,f_2)=\frac{-1}{a(1+b)}$$
$$z_1=-1-a~~~,~~~z_2=0~~~\Rightarrow ~~~R_F(f_1,z_2)=\frac{-1}{b(1+a)}$$

The final residue at $z_1=0$ and $z_2=0$ depends on what $a$ and $b$ are. But it can be only one of the two following values:

$$R_F(z_1,z_2)=\frac{1}{a(1+b)}~~~~~~~or~~~~~~~R_F(z_1,z_2)=\frac{1}{b(1+a)}$$

Clearly, the sum of the four terms does not vanish. It is interesting to note that the two possibilities in $R_F(z_1,z_2)$ cancel either $R_F(f_1,z_2)$ or $R_F(z_1,f_2)$, but the first residue $R_F(f_1,f_2)$ is never cancelled by anything. What went wrong?

**EDIT**

David Speyer asked in the comments what version of the global residue theorem I am using. I am trying to apply the global residue theorem as given in "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris (in the residues chapter, around page 655 in my version of the book). Also, I found an explicit example of it being applied around equations (3.4) - (3.9) in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.5200v1.pdf).

**EDIT 2**

grghxy pointed out that I should look more carefully into possible contributions from poles at infinity. There are three cases to consider:

1) Only $z_1\rightarrow\infty$

In this case $f_1=z_1+O(z_1^0)$ and $f_2=O(z_1^0)$, therefore

$$F(z_1,z_2)\sim\frac{1}{z_1^2}dz_1\wedge dz_2\rightarrow q_1^2\frac{-1}{q_1^2}dq_1\wedge dz_2 =-dq_1\wedge dz_2$$

so we see that there is no pole and therefore no residue in this case.

2) Only $z_2\rightarrow\infty$

Already checked in 1) by symmetry arguments. No pole and therefore no residue at infinity.

3) $z_1\rightarrow\infty$ and $z_2\rightarrow\infty$

This case is a combination of 1) and 2). So $f_1=z_1+O(z_i^0)$ and $f_2=z_2+O(z_i^0)$, therefore

$$F(z_1,z_2)\sim\frac{1}{z_1^2}\frac{1}{z_2^2}dz_1\wedge dz_2\rightarrow q_1^2q_2^2\frac{-1}{q_1^2}\frac{-1}{q_2^2}dq_1\wedge dq_2 =dq_1\wedge dq_2$$

we see that there is no pole and therefore no residue in this case either.

**EDIT 3**

grghxy emphasized in the comments that to have a valid setting for the global residue theorem in $\mathbb{C}^2$, one should not only provide the two form $\omega=F(z_1,z_2)$, but also two effective divisors $D_1$ and $D_2$. Then the theorem works if the poles of $\omega$ are "no worse" than $D_1+D_2$ (the exact meaning of this statement is still mostly mysterious to me). I do know that the $D_i$ are constructed from subvarieties of codimension-1, so basically are hypersurfaces defined by vanishing of scalar functions of $z_1$ and $z_2$. However, it is not clear to me which relation and properties in respect to $\omega$ the $D_i$'s should have in order to qualify as input data for the global residue theorem. So I don't know where to start. Any suggestion?

I guess it will be simpler for me to first start with the simplified problem where

$$f_1(z_1,z_2)=1+a_1 z_1+a_2 z_2~~~~~,~~~~~f_2(z_1,z_2)=1+b_1 z_1+b_2 z_2$$

with this the residues obtained from $F(z_1,z_2)$ are:

$$z_1=\frac{b_2-a_2}{a_2 b_1-a_1 b_2}~~~,~~~z_2=\frac{a_1-b_1}{a_2 b_1-a_1 b_2}~~~\Rightarrow ~~~R_F(f_1,f_2)=\frac{a_2 b_1-a_1 b_2}{(a_1-b_1)(a_2-b_2)}$$
$$z_1=0~~~,~~~z_2=\frac{-1}{b_2}~~~\Rightarrow ~~~R_F(z_1,f_2)=\frac{b_2}{a_2-b_2}$$
$$z_1=\frac{-1}{a_1}~~~,~~~z_2=0~~~\Rightarrow ~~~R_F(f_1,z_2)=\frac{a_1}{b_1-a_1}$$
$$z_1=0~~~,~~~z_2=0~~~\Rightarrow ~~~R_F(z_1,z_2)=1$$

These are all the poles and all the residues that appear in this particular $F(z_1,z_2)$. Now one can check straightforwardly that:

$$R_F(f_1,f_2)+R_F(z_1,f_2)+R_F(f_1,z_2)+R_F(z_1,z_2)=\\~~~~~~~~~~=\frac{a_2 b_1-a_1 b_2}{(a_1-b_1)(a_2-b_2)}+\frac{b_2}{a_2-b_2}+\frac{a_1}{b_1-a_1}+1=0$$

so the global residue theorem is satisfied. If I could find the hidden $D_1$ and $D_2$ that are at work here, I might be able to generalize to the harder problem above. Any suggestions on how to go about here?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the multivariate global residue theorem which you are using? Google is pointing me only to this paper by Griffiths http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183544569 , which is about residues of $n$ functions of $n$ variables.

Comment: @David Speyer : I am trying to apply the global residue theorem as given in "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris (in the residues chapter, around page 655 in my version of the book). Also, I found an explicit example of it being applied around equations (3.4) - (3.9) in the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.5200v1.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll have to wait until I get home to my books to look at this, or wait for someone else to do so. The relevant pages of G&H aren't online. That paper doesn't state the theorem they are using, although it sure looks as if they are factoring their two variable integrand into two factors, which would be consistent with the paper I linked.

Comment: @grghxy : Yes, I did mean to multiply $F(z_1,z_2)$ by $dz_1\wedge dz_2$ to make it a two form, I will edit my question to mention it. I was thinking of having each $\mathbb{C}$ be mapped to a punctured sphere, where the puncture corresponds to a point at infinity that can also contain a residue. Since the contour in $z_1$ and $z_2$ is a polydisc I hope that having a direct product of two spheres as the underlying manifold is compact. Not sure if I make any sense or am addressing your question properly? Let me know if I should think again.

Comment: @grghxy I did consider transformations of the integrand under $z_1\rightarrow 1/q_1$ and/or $z_2\rightarrow 1/q_2$ and it looked like there were no poles at infinity (so at $q_1=0$ and or $q_2=0$) in all the cases. (If I understood the issue you are pointing out correctly.) I will check again!

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Yes, the paper you linked does look very similar to what appears in the book.

Comment: @grghxy Yes, I used the correct differential. I have edited the question above to show how I find that there are no residues at infinity. Let me know if there is a mistake.

Comment: @grghxy I am not completely sure what the difference between the $F(z_1,z_2)$ above and a usual $\omega=g(z_1,z_2)dz_1\wedge dz_2$ is, that appears in all the global residue theorem expressions. Do you mean I should decompose the two form into two one forms? But if I then wedge the two one forms again anyway to apply the theorem, how could that make a difference compared to what $F(z_1,z_2)$ is?

Comment: Sorry, I was mixing up something with $n$ divisors. On a compact complex $n$-manifold, an ordered $n$-tuple of effective divisors $D_1, \dots, D_n$ with $\cap D_i$ finite and a single meromorphic $n$-form $\omega$ with polar divisor no worse than $\sum D_i$ yield a "residue symbol" ${\rm{Res}}_P(\omega/(D_1,\dots,D_n))$ for each $P\in \cap D_i$, and the global theorem is that these sum to 0. In your setup on $\mathbf{P}^1 \times \mathbf{P}^1$, what is the meromorphic 2-form $\omega$ and especially what are the two divisors $D_1, D_2$ so that $\omega$ has poles "no worse" than $D_1+D_2$?

Comment: Let's see if I understand this correctly. Divisors on an $n$-dimensional complex manifold are linear combinations of subvarieties of dimension $(n-1)$, which in turn are each defined as hypersurfaces described by the vanishing of corresponding functions in $n$ variables. Then the intersection of the two divisors are the locations of poles in $\omega$. So, are you saying that in the above example the global residue theorem is only valid if at least two different functions of $z_1$ and $z_2$ exist which both vanish simultaneously only on the $(z_1,z_2)$ tuples of poles in $\omega=F(z_1,z_2)$?

Comment: The subvarieties of codimension-1 are given by a global equation in the case of affine $n$-space, as in your setup.  You need $D_1$ and $D_2$ in $\mathbf{P}^1 \times \mathbf{P}^1$ with finite intersection, but this finite set is not what constrains the poles.  Indeed, by Hartogs the polar locus of $\omega$ (if not empty) is a divisor!  We want the polar part of ${\rm{div}}(\omega)$ to be bounded below by $-(D_1+D_2)$ (i.e., poles of $\omega$ are "no worse" than $D_1+D_2$). But I can't see what are $\omega$, $D_1$, and $D_2$ in your setup. How are you in the setup of the global residue theorem?

Comment: I am pretty sure that $\omega=F(z_1,z_2)$, just out of purely heuristic considerations. $\omega$ is expected to be a two form that has poles and which we take the residues of, so that $F(z_1,z_2)$ satisfies these requirements. If the divisors do not determine the locations of poles, then their purpose is not obvious to me. However, all poles in $F(z_1,z_2)$ are simple, which are the least divergent poles possible. So that whatever $D_1+D_2$ is, if it admits any poles at all, simple poles will be included. Or does the specification "worse poles" classify something different than pole order?

Comment: You mean $\omega = F {\rm{d}}z_1 \wedge {\rm{d}}z_2$?  OK, and then what is $D_1$ and what is $D_2$ (with $D_1+D_2$ an upper bound on the location of polar divisor of $\omega$ and generic pole orders along the components of that divisor)?  The *definition* of the residue symbol in the residue theorem depends crucially on the ordered pair $(D_1, D_2)$; one cannot compute the residue symbol without that information. If you have not defined what are $D_1$ and $D_2$ then you cannot have computed the residue symbols that are appearing in the residue theorem (not even heuristically).

Comment: I am still confused about the $D_i$'s. At least in univariate contour integration residues are simply defined as the coefficient in front of a term in the Laurent series. (I guess in one complex variable the codimension-1 hypersurface is just a constant though, so there very well might be a trivial $D_1$.) The authors of the paper I mentioned earlier successfully applied a global residue theorem without mentioning any $D_1$ or $D_2$ either. Did they use a different theorem? One clearly can compute individual residues using the Jacobian. That is what I do, and I think what is done in the paper.

Comment: Please look at the *definition* of residues in Griffiths & Harris, and at the setup for the global residue theorem in that book (with $M = M' = U = \mathbf{P}^1 \times \mathbf{P}^1$ for the latter).  In each, one has to give $D_1$ and $D_2$ (and $\omega$) satisfying specific conditions as part of the setup, so one cannot apply any of what they do without having defined such data.  All I am asking is: what are your *definitions* of these are which is consistent with their requirements?  (I don't know what is happening in the paper by physicists that you linked; they pull (3.7) out of thin air.)

Comment: Ok, yes, I guess it will be more appropriate to look at what the $D_i$ should be in more detail. My problem is that I never constructed any such data before. Do you know which page of the book describes how the specific $D_i$'s for an $\omega$ are chosen? Also, maybe I can update the question above and show an example where the naive application of the global residue theorem works out even without knowing the $D_i$'s. Then I'll try to construct fitting $D_i$'s going from simple case to hard one.